# Create a list of list from pandas dataframe in python with group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I am beginner in python. I am just wondering, I have this data in a **pandas dataframe**

| type | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |

where each **type** will have three value (it can be different value or same value)

and what I want is to create a **list of list** (or anything, I don't know the exact name since I'm stuck to search the similar question using this vocabulary) but ***group by type column***

expected output is exactly list of list like this:

```
[[1,4,3],[6,2,2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('type').agg(pd.Series.tolist)['value'].tolist()
```

or simply:

```
df.groupby('type').agg(list)['value'].tolist()
```

Edit:

It depends on whether which number do you want to sort upon.. in this case, it will sort on the first element of the list which is `1`.

If you want to reverse you can simply say `k = df.groupby('type').agg(list)['value'].tolist()`

```
k.sort(reverse=True)
```

it will give you `[[6,2,2], [1,4,3]]`. If you want to sort on any of the values of list you have to apply `key=some_function()` accordingly.

Comment: thankyou! it really help. a question, let say i have 100 types (A, B, C, ...etc), how can I keep getting list of list but sort by type column? so in above case, I will definitely get [[1,4,3],[6,2,2]] instead of [[6,2,2], [1,4,3]]. I've tried ```df.sort_values(by=['type']).groupby('type').agg(list)['value'].tolist()``` but didn't work